# Overload resolution in nested namespace with parent namespace

Tags: c++, overload-resolution, name-lookup

I thought that in a nested namespace, anything that is part of the parent (or global) namespace is considered equally for overload resolution, but this example seems to show otherwise.

This works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int) { std::cout << "int\n"; }
void foo(float) { std::cout << "float\n"; }

namespace NS {
    void bar() {
        foo(0);
    }
}

int main() {
    NS::bar();
}
```

The call to `foo(0)` matches `foo(int)` since it is a better match and everything works as expected. However, if I move the declaration of `foo(float)` into the namespace:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int) { std::cout << "int\n"; }

namespace NS {
    void foo(float) { std::cout << "float\n"; }
    void bar() {
        foo(0);
    }
}

int main() {
    NS::bar();
}
```

The call to `foo(0)` now calls `foo(float)`!

I have searched through https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution and many other such pages to find the rule that explains this, but I seem to be missing it. Can someone please explain which of the many complex overload resolution rules causes this, or is it something else?

**EDIT**
I just discovered it is even weirder. Even if the `foo` inside the namespace *doesn't match at all*, it still won't use the one outside. This just completely fails to compile:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int) { std::cout << "int\n"; }

namespace NS {
    void foo(float, float) { std::cout << "float\n"; }
    void bar() {
        foo(0);
    }
}

int main() {
    NS::bar();
}
```

Comment: You think that's weird? You haven't considered the alternative. If an overload set was always formed from everything in sight, modifying your program even slightly would not be possible. Imagine you include a new header for some utility, but then other unrealted functions in the file suddenly work differently! Simply because the new header included better matches in overload resolution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point is [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup), which happens before overload resolution.

When the name `foo` is found at the namespace `NS`, name lookup stops, the further scopes won't be checked, the global `foo` won't be found at all. Then there's only one candidate in overload resolution, and `int` could convert to `float` implicitly, then `NS::foo(float)` gets called at last.

(emphasis mine)

> name lookup examines the scopes as described below, until it finds at least one declaration of any kind, **at which time the lookup stops and no further scopes are examined**.

Comment: Can you refer me to the part of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup that says this?

Comment: @Baruch Added to the answer.